# Why doesn't Django set the cookie when the view is called

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am trying to set and unset a Django cookie based on a form with a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked I would like the cookie to be set.

Passing the value of the checkbox to the view is working correctly, but setting and unsetting the cookie is not.

This is the view:

```
def filter(request):

    tasks = list()

    if request.POST.get('today') == 'yes':
        tasks.extend(Task.objects(when='today'))
        print('get tasks today')

    response = render(request, 'index.html', {'tasks': tasks})

    if request.POST.get('today') == 'yes':
         response.set_cookie('today', 'yes')
         print('set cookie today')
    else:
        response.set_cookie('today', 'no')
        print('cookie not set today')

    return response
```

Whether or not to set the cookie is determined by this code:

```
{{request.COOKIES.today}}
<form action="filter" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="today" value="yes" {% if request.COOKIES.today == 'yes' %}checked{% endif %}> Today</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Show" class="btn btn-warning col-12 btn-sm"/>
</form>
```

In my template I use `{{request.COOKIES.today}}` to check the value of the cookie. What's happening is strange. If I click the checkbox the cookie is not set, as I expect it to be and the checkbox is not checked when the page reloads. But if I select the checkbox again, then the cookie is set and the checkbox is selected.

Am I making a mistake somewhere, or missing something. I am trying to get the cookie to be set the first time the form is submitted.

Comment: You are outputting the state of the cookies _sent in the request_, which of course won't exist yet with the first form submission, because the cookie will only be set together with the *response.* The *next* request will then contain the cookie.

Comment: Thankyou, that makes sense based on what I'm seeing. I'm trying to get my head around what I should do to fix it (I know it's probably simple).

Comment: Do the `if request.POST.get('today') == 'yes'` check *before* rendering the template, so you can pass a yes/no boolean into your template to indicate whether cookies _will_ be set…? It's not quite clear what exactly you want to achieve. Output the cookies you *received*, or indicate which cookies will be *sent*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I want to set the cookies in the view, and then when the template is rendered have those values I set be available in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' the problem by using a HttpResponseRedirect Object

After setting the cookie I redirect to a view that reads the cookie and lists the tasks for the 'time period' corresponding to the cookie.

```
def filter(request):
    response = HttpResponseRedirect('/index')
    if request.POST.get('today') == 'yes':
         response.set_cookie('today', 'yes')
         print('set cookie today')
    else:
        response.set_cookie('today', 'no')
        print('cookie not set today')
    return response


def index(request):
     tasks = list()
     if request.COOKIES.get('today') == 'yes':
         tasks.extend(Task.objects(when='today'))
     return render(request, 'index.html', {'tasks': tasks})
```